Are bounded monotone functions piecewise continuous or at least their Laplace transform unique?
Suppose you have a function $h: \mathbb{R}_{+} \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ that is monotone decreasing (thus bounded) and locally integrable. Can we conclude that it is piecewise continuous?
Obviously, due to the monotonicity there are only countably many discontinuities, but that is not good enough. There could be accumulation points, where the piecewise continuity breaks apart. But maybe there is some workaround.
What I am really interested in, though, is whether the Laplace transform of those functions is unique, i.e. that I can conclude $h_1 = h_2$ for such functions $h_1,h_2$ that have the same Laplace transform in an interval $\lambda \in [0,\Lambda]$.

Hint for the first question: Is it possible to construct a monotonically decreasing function $\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ that has discontinuities at the points $\{1-\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \mathbb{R}_+$?
As for the second question, as soon as there is no continuity, you can't guarantee that $L\{h_1\}=L\{h_2\}\implies h_1=h_2$, as you can set the values of $h_1$ to overlap with values at $h_2$ at all but one point, which changes nothing in terms of integration. So the implication above doesn't even hold in the case of piecewise continuous functions (I guess it technically can, if you are very strict about the way you define piecewise continuity, but using the universally agreed upon definition, it doesn't). For more details, see the Wikipedia article for Laplace transform.

I guess I was too vague/general in my original question. The functions I care about are of the form $h(r) = \int_{r}^{\infty} \pi ([u,\infty))du$ with $\pi$ some measure on $(0,\infty)$ such that $\int_{(0,\infty)} (r\wedge r^2) \pi (dr) < \infty$. So what I want is to show the equality of $\pi$ which is equivalent to the equivalence of the functions $h$. The proof, where this is from just states that this follows by "standard arguments of analytic continuation", but I have no clue what these standard arguments are supposed to be.

I'm pretty sure $h$ is continuous? I mean, the implication does hold for continuous functions as per Wikipedia article.

Yeah, I think you are right. Sometimes you don't see the tree from the forest :D.
But I think I also misunderstood the wording in the proof. The analytic continuation part was probably meant in a different way, I have realised. Anyway, I am gonna accept your answer, because it technically answered my question, even though that was not what I was looking for in the end.

Consider the probability on $(0,1)$ concentrated on rationals such that if the mass $p_r$ on the rational $r=p/q$ (where $p$ and $q$ have no common factor) is $C/q^3$ where $C$ is the constant such that $ \sum _r p_r=1.$ If $\Pr(X=r)=p_r$ then $x\mapsto \Pr(X\leq x)$ is monotone increasing on $[0.1]$ and piecewise continuous on no subinterval of $[0,1].$
